# No service registered for .NET Core Kestrel application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a console application that I'm trying to get to run Kestrel.  The code files are all the boilerplate files from an empty ASP.Core application:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
}
```

However, when I run it I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IStartup' has been registered.
```

My proj file is:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" version="2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: How did you run the app? I tested your code within VS 2017 debug mode, as well as using `dotnet app.dll` and worked in both cases!

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh Built and run with the former CLI.  The console application was created with it as well `dotnet new console`>

Comment: I guess the issue with resolving the dependencies, I will test the `new console` method, meanwhile can you try VS 2017 if feasible?

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh Thanks.  Unfortunately I only have Rider at present.

Comment: I did `dotnet new console` then updated program.cs and csproj with your code then `dotnet restore` then `dotnet run` and it worked.

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh thanks, do you have the same references as I do?

Comment: I have these: using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

Comment: Yes for csproj I did exactly as you.

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh I meant in your project file.

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh I'm confused then.  Thanks for having a go.  I assume you're using core 2.0?

Comment: Yes, core 2.0, OS: Windows 10. What OS are you using?

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh Exactly the same. I'll try starting again from scratch. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, I couldn't reproduce the reported issue:

I found single reference regarding the exception `System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IStartup' has been registered.` you mentioned, below quoted from [Reference](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/430#issuecomment-310105699):

> its the ASP.NET Core configuration system that throws this exception
>   stating that there is no IStartup class.
>
> I'm not this familiar with what you are doing here, but it seems that
>   you're doing your **configuration in an incorrect order**.